# Passing a dataset from Oracle to C# gives me an instruction pointer error

Tags: c#, oracle12c

I've got the following block of C# code to pass a variable into an Oracle 12c procedure and return a dataset:

```
    public void Show_Data()
    {
        try
        {
            OracleConnection conn = GetConnection();
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnCST"].ToString();

                OracleCommand cmd3 = new OracleCommand();
                cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd3.CommandText = "CST_FEEDBACK";
                cmd3.Connection = conn;

                cmd3.Parameters.Add("LineID", OracleType.Number).Value = hLineID.Value;
                cmd3.Parameters.Add("Emp_out", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                //connection2.Open();

                var SearchAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd3);
                var ds = new DataSet();
                SearchAdapter.Fill(ds);

                ResponseRepeater.DataSource = ds;
                ResponseRepeater.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

When the code gets to the line `var ds = new Dataset();` it fails with the following message:

> Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is
>   not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has
>   been optimized away.

Can someone tell me what this means and/or how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem frequently occurs when debugging code that was optimized by the compiler.

Switch to Build Configuration "Debug", or if that is already active, then go to Project -> Properties -> tab [Build], look for [x] Optimize code, and uncheck it:

[image: Optimize-Code.png]

Comment: My configuration dropdown was, in fact, set to "Release" and when I switched it to "Debug" it worked.  However, does that mean it won't work when I publish the code?

Comment: Optimized code is great, and recommended for a Release version, but not suitable for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try Oracle Managed Data access dll(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) for oracle connection. And use any oracle helper class(http://read.pudn.com/downloads153/sourcecode/windows/dotnet/671399/SQL%2BOleDb%2BOracle%2BNpg_helper/SqlHelper/OracleHelper.cs__.htm). Now you can use like normal SQL Query.

```
   OracleConnectionService OraCon = new OracleConnectionService();
            var cc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleProdContext"].ToString();
       OracleConnection _con = new OracleConnection(cc);
       OracleConnection = _con;
       TextCommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                     var resultSet = OracleHelper.ExecuteScalar(OraCon.OracleConnection, OraCon.TextCommandType, OracleQuery);
 var result = resultSet.Tables[0];
```

If you want to change to Collection use some generic convert DataRow to Collection code is available on Net.